# JSoup get HTML table data from website

Tags: java, html, parsing, html-table, jsoup

I'd like to get data from a HTML table which looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="30" class="listWeekday">Mo</td>    
    <td class="listStart">05:00</td>
    <td class="listEnd">08:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td... unknown value of Start and End td's> </td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="30" class="listWeekday">Tu</td>
   <td.. same as Monday, continues so till Friday></td></tr>
```

I like to parse this table with Jsoup. I tried to use the select() method with "td.listWeekday" running in

```
for (Element elem : values) {
  S.o.P(elem.text()); }
```

Works fine, but when I try to get the listStart values it collects the Data from all days, but I like to seperate them, so I get the listStart and listEnd values for each day.

I think this is possible, but I don't even have a clue where to start, because the number of listStart and listEnd's change every day.

Comment: You will have to develop the code to do this. JSoup does not support you in this since (for you) it is only a search library. Any more advanced behaviour is up to the developer

Comment: Ah Ok, I hoped this was possible with Jsoup. I think I'll figure something else out. Thank you

Comment: Can you complete the HTML code in the post please? I think there's a solution with Jsoup.

Comment: I got the complete HTML code here http://pastebin.com/Sa2MRCTQ

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Do you want to get only the first `<td class="listStart">` of each day, or do you want to get them all, but separated by week day?

Comment: I like to get them all, but separated by week day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing tables with rowspan entries is not straightforward in JSoup or any other HTML library I know. What you could do in your case is to keep a simple variable with the current day while cycling over all rows. Something like this:

```
String URL = "http://pastebin.com/raw/Sa2MRCTQ";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements trs = doc.select("tr:has(td.liste-startzeit)");
String currentDay = null;
for (Element tr : trs){
    Element tdDay = tr.select("td.liste-wochentag").first();
    if (tdDay!=null){
        currentDay = tdDay.text();
    }   
    Element tdStart = tr.select("td.liste-startzeit").first();

    System.out.println(currentDay +" : "+tdStart.text());
}
```